# Register/Alter MIME associations in asp.net mvc Web Setup Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, iis-7, mime, setup-project

I'm making a Web Setup Project of my Asp.net Mvc project. I'd like the installer to change some MIME associations on IIS7. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad. This would be done in web.config

http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/25/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config.aspx